# Integrating DB info from inside of an html table to output a single row's info to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating an admin section to be able to update user info. I have a table constructed through a while loop that displays all of the user info I am calling for. I then added an edit option and creating an customeredit.php page that I will be creating input fields into that I can type in my changes and submit.

My question is how can I program my code that when clicking the edit button in a single row it recognizes that rows ID and associates that with the record?

I have not attached any code for the customeredit.php file because it is only has the base format in it. Do I need to insert anything in the customeredit.php file to make this work?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
?>                 
<table class="tableproduct">
    <tr>
        <th class="thproduct">ID</th>
        <th class="thproduct">First Name</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Last Name</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Email</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Username</th>
        <th class="thproduct">Group</th>
    </tr>   
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?> </td> 
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['username']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['group']; ?> </td>
        <td class="tdproduct">
             <a href='editusers.phpid'='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>EDIT</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Relevant Code inside of edituser.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = new User();

 if(Session::exists('home')) {
echo '<p>' . Session::flash('home') . '</p>';
 }
if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
Redirect::to('index.php');
 }

?>
```

Some of the input fields I will be entering into edituser.php

```
<div class="content">
                <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname"  class="inputbar" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->firstname); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="lastname" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->lastname); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->email); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="email" class="inputbar" name="username" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>" required>
                        </div>  

                            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                            <label for="signinButton">
                                <input type="submit" id="signinButton" value="Update">
                            </label>
                    </form>

 <?php
     $_GET['id'];
 ?>
```

PHP that shows how I get the CURRENT users info who is signed in.

```
<?php
if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'firstname' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'lastname' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'email' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'username' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        )
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {

        try{
            $user->update(array(
                'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'username' => Input::get('username')
            ));

            Session::flash('home', 'Your details have been updated successfully.');
            Redirect::to('edituser.php');

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add input text field to display the data you are retrieving from database.

instead of $row['rowname'];

you can add

```
<input type="text" name="product_<?php echo $product_id;?>" value="<?php echo $row['rowname'];?>">
```

and send to server using post method.

Comment: So all I would have do to is go into my customeredit.php file and type in the echo code? Would this work for any record I hit edit on? Ideally I would want something that recognized a selected id, rather than just outputting the info from that table. I will be putting input fields that echo info from the db inside. Then allow the ability to update the information.

Comment: isn't that what this is doing? <a href='editusers.phpid'='<?      php echo $row['id']; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
                    </tr>

Answer (score -1):

change your edit link line to

`<td class="tdproduct"><a href='editusers.php?id'='<?php echo $row['id'];?>'>EDIT</a></td>`

Missing the question mark after .php will lead to syntax error . When you get to the editusers.php page , you can then access the id by using $_GET("id");

Comment: Do I need to add anything with the GET statement? It will recognize everything by just adding in $_GET("id");   ?

Comment: you will use that to get the specific user from the database like `select * from users where ID = <?php  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET("id")) ?>`